# Facebook login popup not closing on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk

When I use the JS SDK, and call the login action on my mobile chrome browser, it opens the login dialogue in a new window, but when I authenticate, the page just goes blank and doesn't close the popup or go back to my website.  When I manually close the tab, and go back to my website and refresh, I am logged in.

Am I doing something wrong?

Channel file is correct, running off of a media temple http connection.

Thanks in advance,
HPC

Comment: Turns out it's just on Chrome on IOS, safari seems to be ok - it redirects back, but doesn't close the tab.  Good enough.

Comment: Still stays open and blank after Facebook login, window doesn't close.  iOS 8.0.2 Safari.